# Model variable not able to recognize Model properties in ASP MVC3 DropDownListFor

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-2, model

Below is the code from my View. For whatever reason, the model properties (i.e. `.TableName`) are not being recognized as such. Below is the error message:

`CS1061: 'PagedList.IPagedList<Monet.Models.FollowUpItems>' does not contain a definition for 'TableName' and no extension method 'TableName' accepting a first argument of type 'PagedList.IPagedList<Monet.Models.FollowUpItems>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Here is the code from the View's Index page. This page is needed to return a list of items from the SQL table `FollowUpItems`:

```
@model PagedList.IPagedList<Monet.Models.FollowUpItems>


@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

@using PagedList.Mvc; 
@using PagedList;


<h2>Follow Up Items</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <span id="searchBox" class="boxMe" >
            <form method="post">
              @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.TableName, (SelectList)ViewBag.tableID)
              @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.IssueType, (SelectList)ViewBag.issueID)
              @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Status, (SelectList)ViewBag.statusID)

            <input type="image" src="@Url.Content("~/Content/Images/Filter.bmp")" alt="Filter" style="padding-top: 0px;" />
            <a href="#" style="padding-left: 30px;"></a>
            </form>
        </span>
        <br />
        <br />
        <span id="programExplanation" style="width: 500px; float:left; padding: 5px; margin-left: 25px;"></span>

    <span class="error" style="clear: both;">
        @ViewBag.ErrorMessage
    </span>
    <span class="msg">
        @ViewBag.Message
    </span>
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
}
```

The drop down lists in question are used as sort criteria for the original list of items. The selectable drop down items are not reflected in the database, however the specific properties each represents are present. For good measure here is the `FollowUpItems` model

```
public partial class FollowUpItems
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string TableName { get; set; }
    public string IssueType { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
    public string LastUpdateBy { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> LastUpdateOn { get; set; }
    public string Key1 { get; set; }
    public string Key2 { get; set; }
    public string Notes { get; set; }
}
```

And here is code from the controller:

```
        //Sort info
        string table = String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(dropDownSelection["Table"]) ? "%" : dropDownSelection["Table"];
        string issue = String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(dropDownSelection["IssueType"]) ? "%" : dropDownSelection["IssueType"];
        string status = String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(dropDownSelection["Status"]) ? "%" : dropDownSelection["Status"];

        //Set dropdown list items based on previous values
        var tableOptions = new[] { new { Text = "--Table Name--", Value = "%" }, new { Text = "CE", Value = "AgentContEd" }, new { Text = "AgentProductTraining", Value = "C" } };
        var issueOptions = new[] { new { Text = "--Issue Type--", Value = "%" }, new { Text = "Warning", Value = "W" }, new { Text = "Error", Value = "E" } };
        var statusOptions = new[] { new { Text = "--Status Type--", Value = "%" }, new { Text = "Open", Value = "O" }, new { Text = "Under Review", Value = "U" } };

        ViewBag.tableID = new SelectList(tableOptions, "Value", "Text", table);
        ViewBag.issueID = new SelectList(issueOptions, "Value", "Text", issue);
        ViewBag.statusID = new SelectList(statusOptions, "Value", "Text", status);
```

Comment: the model is NOT a list. please clarify. I'm confused.

Comment: That's basically what the problem was. See my discussion with Forty-Two below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is you're trying to access a property that's not in your actual Model.  TableName, IssueType and Status are part of the items in the list, not the list itself.  When you post the form, how would you retrieve your filter information? The drop downs aren't actually part of your items, but for the filter you're wanting to apply.

You should make viewmodel to handle all of your UI information - which is actually what you're trying to access.

```
public class YourViewModel
{
  public PagedList.IPagedList<Monet.Models.FollowUpItems> itemList {get;set;}
  public string TableName {get;set;}
  public string IssueType {get;set;}
  public string Status {get;set;}


}
```

Then you'd post your viewmodel to your controller action, and based on the selections handle the filters.

While you're there, you could also save your select lists in the view model, instead of the view bag it will probably make life a little easier in the long term.

Comment: No, it is for a list of items. I'll make an edit to my post to indicate that. Thx

Comment: updated the answer.. you'll need to loop through your model to access each item individually

Comment: I think I misunderstood your question. The page needs to display a list of items in a section below (not included in the code, that section works fine), but I need the form I mentioned in the post to display a couple drop down lists. So yeah, the `DropDownListFor` items in question only need to display one item. They are also being set in the controller (I'll add this to the post as well).

Comment: I think I get your issue now.  Try creating a viewmodel, and having that store your view information.  Passing that around in your controller will make filtering/sorting significantly easier than in a viewbag.

Comment: Why the downvote?  The problem is that he's wanting to access UI information in a DropdownListFor which is an error. Creating a viewmodel would allow him to access his model, and then create the dropdown filters he's looking for.

Comment: I agree. maybe wrong guess, but there was nothing sloppy about it.

Comment: People love anonymous down-voting.  This is a perfectly valid answer.

Comment: sadly gives ppl a feeling of superiority. I wrote a whole rant about it on meta that got a net score -40

Answer (score 1):

Think about your situation in simpler terms to get a better understanding.

You have a list of objects.

Each object in the list has a collection of properties.

```
public class ModelObject
{
  public string ModelProperty {get; set}
}
var myModels = new List<ModelObject>();
```

Now, you can use the dot operator to access properties from an object.  This is no problem:

```
 ModelObject.ModelProperty
```

But you cannot use the dot operator on a *list*.

You need to *iterate* the list, or use something like `First()` or `FirstOrDefault()` before you can access properties of a *member* of the list via the dot operator.

Comment: Don't think I'm explaining this right, or maybe I don't get your answer. The drop down lists that are in question are used simply to store filter criteria. When the user navigates from page 1 to 2, the selected sort criteria needs to stay selected in the drop down lists, which is why I'm setting them in the controller. The values aren't themselves tied to any records, they just represent the list of potential values for a specific field.

Comment: I use the same code in the `Edit` view that corresponds to the exact same Model/Controller. Here is the code that works: `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Status, (SelectList)ViewBag.CategoryID)`. It's the same syntax, so I'm confused as to why the `Edit` view can see these properties while the `Index` view cannot see any.

Comment: It's different because your model is different.  Look at your @model command at the top of your EditView - it's not an IPagedList, it's probably of FollowUpItems, which is why you can access it.

Comment: `@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.TableName...`  won't work when the model is a list.  What is the model passed to the edit view? Is it a list?

Comment: No it is not, I see what you are getting at now.